# HTTP Response code for "Please wait a little bit"

Tags: http, rest, httpresponse

What is the best HTTP response code for the server to send if it wants the client to wait for a little bit of time and then try the request again?

Right now, I'm using:

```
409 Conflict
```

But this doesn't feel quite right...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Depending on why you want them to wait, the status codes will be different. Codes that start with 4 signify client errors. If the request was done properly I would not use a 400 code. Statuses that start with 5 are for server errors. If you are asking the HTTP requestor to wait because of problems on your side, I'd go with 503.

I came across this issue writing a web service to check if a file is finished processing. If it is done. I am returning 200, if it is not I don't want to give an error code. It would be more appropriate to use one that starts with 2 (success.) In this case the best standard code would probably be "202 Accepted" [The HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.3) describes it as:

> The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed.

Comment: This actually is the best answer I believe after carefully reading the spec description.

Answer (score 13):

You can use 503 + "retry-after" header as recommended in HTTP RFC - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.5.4.

Comment: This is the one I had to use because webapp wouldn't let me add error codes that it did not recognize (the "429" and "420" codes from the other answer).

Answer (score 10):

Two options come to mind, assuming you're trying to implement a rate-limiting scheme (otherwise, [Alexei's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12449556/23897) may be more applicable).

- 429 [Too Many Requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585)

> The 429 status code indicates that the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting").

> The response representations SHOULD include details explaining the
> condition, and MAY include a Retry-After header indicating how long
> to wait before making a new request.

- 420 [Enhance Your Calm](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses), nonstandard, used by Twitter, and included here because its name amuses me.

> Returned by the version 1 Search and Trends APIs when you are being rate limited.

Comment: [Lenina Huxley: "Enhance your calm, John Spartan."](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106697/quotes?qt=qt1535085)